# javascript eventlistener not working with php

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to show and hide a table when the user clicks on a button. I used JavaScript's `addEventlistener()` to achieve this but when I click on the button, the table only appears for a short period. Everything else is working as intended.

```
var btn = document.querySelector(".btn");
var tb = document.querySelector("table");
tb.style.display = "none"
btn.addEventListener("click", function(){
    tb.style.display = "block"
});
```

```php
<?php   
    global $resul;
    global $query;
    error_reporting(E_ERROR|E_PARSE);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($resul);
    echo "<tr><td>".$row["id"]."</td><td>".$row["np"]."</td><td>" 
                   .$row ['center']."</td><td>".$row['mg'].
                   "</td><td>".$row["decs"]." "."</td></tr>";

    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: @JayBlanchard "The indenting of the code is so bad it makes my eyes cross." is an unneeded comment. Simply stating "The indenting of the code makes it hard to read." would have been sufficient.

Comment: @JayBlanchard I understand completely that it's a joke. However this is a professional Q&A website and brahim is a "New contributor" who may or may not know that this is a joke.

Comment: Where is the opening `<table>` tag? I don't see one.

Comment: I think they've left out a lot of relevant code @FunkFortyNiner

Comment: @JayBlanchard it's missing a lot of code, IMHO.

Comment: Correct grammar and format code

Answer (score 0):

It is a little hard to tell from the code you posted (need more details), but since you specify that you are using a submit button to do this, I suggest you to change the `<button type="submit"...>` tag for `<button type="button"...>`.

Also I advice you to change your JS event listener function to:

1. Receive the `event` object

   ```
   btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){ ... }
   ```
2. Prevent the default behaviour of `button`, by adding

   ```
   event.preventDefault();
   ```

to your JS listener function, I always put this at the very first line inside the function's code.

Again post more details about the code to give you an answer.

Comment: i'm using php with js so i can't change the <button type="button" >

Comment: As I request in the response, more code will go a long way in order to find a viable solution. Also PHP is scripting you can things like <button type="button"><?php echo 'Hello World';?></button>